# put a value to associative array of value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a question in term of PHP arrays, what I want to do is put a value to associative array.

```
//before
$a = array(
       array(
         'name' => 'test1',
         'email' => 'test@test.com',
         'desc' => 'Who know1',
         'button_link' => 'yest2'
        ),
       array(
         'name' => 'test2',
         'email' => 'test2@test.com',
         'desc' => 'Who know2',
         'button_link' => 'yest2'
    ) 
);

$b = array(
      array(
        'item1' => 'value1',
        'item2' => 'value2'
       ),
      array(
        'item1' => 'value3',
        'item2' => 'value4'
    )
 );
```

I'd like to put `$b['item1']` and `$b['item2']` a value into $a['desc'], . like below...

```
//after
$after_combile = array(
   array(
     'name' => 'test1',
     'email' => 'test@test.com',
     'desc' => 'Who know1 $b["item1"] $b["item2"]',
     'button_link' => 'yest2'
    ),
   array(
     'name' => 'test2',
     'email' => 'test2@test.com',
     'desc' => 'Who know2 $b["item1"] $b["item2"]',
     'button_link' => 'yest2'
   ) 
);
```

I had tried many ways like `array_walk` and so..

I want to output exactly is below

***output**

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array 
        'name' => 'test1',
        'email' => 'test@test.com',
        'desc' => 'Who know1 value1' value2',
        'button_link' => 'yest2'
  1 => 
    array 
     '  name' => 'test2',
        'email' => 'test2@test.com',
        'desc' => 'Who know2 value3 value1',
        'button_link' => 'yest2'
```

**sorry guys my question was unclear.**

Comment: No default function can achieve that itself, you have to loop through those arrays and create the new array accordingly.

Comment: Use double-quotes instead. Variables don't interpolate inside single-quotes.

Comment: That is not their code, that is what they want the output to look like, giving an example of where the value should appear

Comment: @Keiichi Wada: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Could you please add the expected output to your question?

Comment: Thank you very much, guys!!! 
what i got amazing is solved very quickly!!
I love you guys!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'test1',
        'email' => 'test@test.com',
        'desc' => 'Who know1',
        'button_link' => 'yest2'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'test2',
        'email' => 'test2@test.com',
        'desc' => 'Who know2',
        'button_link' => 'yest2'
    )
);

$b = array(
    array(
        'item1' => 'value1',
        'item2' => 'value2'
    ),
    array(
        'item1' => 'value3',
        'item2' => 'value4'
    )
);

$after_combile = array();

foreach($a as $k => $array) {
    $array['desc'] .= implode(' ', $b[$k]);
    $after_combile[] = $array;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! I did it with your way!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array_map(function($a,$b){
   $a['desc'] .= ' '.implode(', ',$b);
   return $a;
},$a,$b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your are using comparable keys:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++) {
    $a[$i]['desc'] = $a[$i]['desc'].$b[$i]['item1'].$b[$i]['item2'];
}
```

Comment: You are very welcome. All of the answers given do the same thing, but @PastorBones' is the most elegant. Note that your initial array sort will be important.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$after_combile = array();

foreach($a as $key=>$array) {
    $array["desc"] .= " ".implode(" ",$b[$key]); 
    $after_combile[] = $array;
}

print_r($after_combile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `array_walk` has better performance in addition to be not dirty:

```
<?php
$a = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'test1',
            'email' => 'test@test.com',
            'desc' => 'Who know1',
            'button_link' => 'yest2'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'test2',
            'email' => 'test2@test.com',
            'desc' => 'Who know2',
            'button_link' => 'yest2'
        ) 
);
$b = array(
        array(
            'item1' => 'value1',
            'item2' => 'value2'
        ),
        array(
            'item1' => 'value3',
            'item2' => 'value4'
        )
);
array_walk($a, function(&$arr, $key){
    global $b;
    $arr['desc'] .= " ".implode(" ", $b[$key]);
});
?>
```

Comment: it's cool! 
seems quite shorter code, your way man :)
thanks!!